# Select/Deselect multiple check boxes using Jquery in loop(Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I working on RoR, I have a two loops inside that i am displaying records with check boxes.

```
<%= form_tag some_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  For loop
    <%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', value %> Name
    For loop
      <%= check_box_tag 'ids_of_second_loop[]', value %> Name
    end
  end
<%= submit_tag "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

Now i wanted to apply a jquery where i can select/ deselect the checkboxes.

I can do if its not in the loop straight forward,

I am referring below link for implementation,
[link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/)

Loop Output...

[image]

How to achieve it...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that clear. Do you need to check/uncheck all child checkboxes when you check/uncheck uno of the checkboxes from the first loop? can you post a real code example?

Comment: Yes exactly right, Edited my Que above....

Comment: It is easy if you give first part html in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
<%= form_tag some_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  For loop
    <%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', value, class: 'parent' %> Name
    <div class='children'>
      For loop
        <%= check_box_tag 'ids_of_second_loop[]', value %> Name
      end
    </div>
  end
<%= submit_tag "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

note that "div class='children'" after the checkbox and the class "parent" on all parent checkboxes

then, javascript

```
$('input.parent').on('change',function(){
  $(this).next('.children').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

it searches the next div with class 'children' after the clicked checkbox, then, it searches all inputs with type=checkbox inside that div, and sets the prop "checked" to the value returned by the current input clicked

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle :

```
$("#button").click(function () {    
    if($("#test")[0].checked)
    {
        $("#test")[0].checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#test")[0].checked = true;
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8wvv1ky/

Comment: Can you please provide me the working example in http://jsfiddle.net/, where it should consist of loop.